# Perl JSON arrays within a parent key

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I have created a script to get some information from various external sources, the results should then be in `json` format. There is a lot of data and I push everything to an array in a loop, then print the `json` array after everything has been completed, an extract of that loop part of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON -convert_blessed_universally;
use strict;
use warnings;
my @json_arr;
my @servers = ("SERVER1", "SERVER2");
my @details = ("SERVER1,10.1.2.3,Suse Linux",
               "SERVER2,10.1.2.4,Windows 10",
               "SERVER3,10.1.2.5,Windows XP");
my $json = JSON->new->convert_blessed;

foreach my $server(@servers) {
    foreach (@details) {
        my @detail = split(',',$_);
        if ($server eq $detail[0]) {
          push @json_arr, {name => "$server", ip => "$detail[1]", os => "$detail[2]"};
      }
   }
}
my $result = $json->encode(\@json_arr);
print $result;
```

This gives an output of:

```
[
   {
      "name" : "SERVER1",
      "ip" : "10.1.2.3",
      "os" : "Suse Linux",
   },
   {
      "name" : "SERVER2",
      "ip" : "10.1.2.4",
      "os" : "Widows 10"
   }
]
```

and a screenshot:

[image]

I am however trying to do it by setting a key element instead and having the additional data as children of the device name, i.e:

```json
{
  "instance" : [
    {
      "SERVER1" : {
        "ip" : "10.1.2.3",
        "os" : "Suse Linux"
      },
      "SERVER2" : {
         "ip" : "10.1.2.4",
         "os" : "Windows 10"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So I have tried a few things, including something like the below, then pushing to array, but I am getting funny results and just not getting the desired results.

```perl
my $json = '{
   "instance" : [
       $server => {
          ip => "$detail[0]",
          os => "$detail[1]"
       }
   ] 
}';
push @json_arr, $json;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only takes a small re-arrangement

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::XS;

...

my @json_ary;

foreach my $server (@servers) {
    foreach (@details) {
        my @detail = split /,/; 
        if ($server eq $detail[0]) {
            #push @json_ary, {name => "$server", ip => "$detail[1]" ...
            push @json_ary, 
                { $server => { ip => $detail[1], os => $detail[2] } } 
        }
    }   
}

print Dumper \@json_ary;

# Encode `{ instance => \@json_ary }` for the desired output
my $json = JSON->new->convert_blessed;
my $result = $json->pretty->encode( { instance => \@json_ary } );

say $result;
```

A few notes

- No need for quotes around variables, since they get evaluated anyway (`"$detail[0]"` --> `$detail[0]` etc)
- No need for quotes around hash keys, as a syntax convenience: `key => 'value'` is OK (and if the value is a variable it's just `key => $var`).  That is, as long as there are no spaces in the key name
- One way to pretty-print an existing JSON string:

  ```
  print JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->encode(decode_json $json_str);
  ```

---

There may be a question of whether a hashref around each server entry (JSON objects) is needed or not; the above was confirmed in a comment after a discussion so I settled with it.

But if the output only needs a hashref with entries for servers in the array (and not an array of hashrefs for each server) then the code in the question can be modified to

```
my %server_details;

foreach my $server (@servers) {
    foreach (@details) {
        my @detail = split /,/; 
        if ($server eq $detail[0]) {
            $server_details{$server} = { ip => $detail[1], os => $detail[2] }
        }
    }   
}
```

Now this hash has details for all servers, and can be encoded with the key `instance`. Then it is not clear to me what the overall structure should be; one option is

```
my $result = JSON->pretty->encode( { instance => [ \%server_details ] }  );
```

This would be suitable if there is more data in reality.  If not then there may not be any need for an arrayref, but encode the usual

```
{ instance => \%server_details }
```

Comment: That's it! The odd thing is, I did this, but I do not have that code to see why it did not work when I did this, nevertheless, this solved my question. Thanks, @Zdim

Comment: @Gerry Great, most welcome :).  Yeah, could've even been some silly detail.

Comment: @Gerry Updated a little -- a couple of comments, and a way to print a JSON string nicely

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks Zdim, I did not realize initially that the `instance` key was not part of the initial answer. PS! Thanks for the `pretty` print, but I actually do it as `$result = $json->pretty->encode( { instance => \@json_ary } );` then `print $result`

Comment: @ikegami "_that's not what your code produces_" -- hang on?  My code produces literally (copy-pasted from it), an array with elements `{ $server => { ip => $detail[1], os => $detail[2] } }` (where `@detail` is remade for each `$server`).  Then it encodes `{ instance => \that_array }` ... (am I going blind?)

Comment: Your code produces `{ "instance" : [ { "SERVER1" : { "ip" : "10.1.2.3",  "os" : "Suse Linux" } }, { "SERVER2" : { "os" : "Windows 10",  "ip" : "10.1.2.4" } } ] }`. Count the number of elements in the array... (1 needed, 2 produced by you)

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, there are questions about what exactly is needed.  (We had a long exchange, of a few dozen comments, in the beginning to clarify this as the iniital posting was rather different.  Then we removed them as irrelevant.)  I added a section to my answer.  I think that what is in the question now is a simplification of what they have, and these hash/hashref's and arrays may need more components.

Comment: @Gerry  "_I actually do it as..._"  -- ah, of course :)  I got carried away with the idea of having a bare JSON string. Adjust that in my post.

Comment: @Gerry  Also, I added a section following ikegami's observation that my original answer creates a structure different from what the last snippet in the question seems to indicate. (What differs from the one before it -- fix that perhaps so they agree to what you need?)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are adding hashes to an array (`push @json_arr, ...`) when you mean to add to a hash (`$instance{ $server_name } = ...`).

```perl
my %servers = map { $_ => 1 } @servers;

my %instance;
for ( @details ) {
   my ( $name, $ip, $os ) = split /,/;
   next if !$servers{ $name };

   $instance{ $name } = {
      ip => $ip,
      os => $os,
   };
}

my @instances = \%instance;

my $data = { instance => \@instances };
```

Or using `map`:

```perl
my %servers = map { $_ => 1 } @servers;

my %instance = (
   map { $_->[0] => { ip => $_->[1], os => $_->[2] } }
      grep $servers{ $_->[0] },
         map [ split /,/ ],
            @details
);

my @instances = \%instance;

my $data = { instance => \@instances };
```

This produces the following, as requested:

```json
{
   "instance" : [
      {
         "SERVER1" : {
            "ip" : "10.1.2.3",
            "os" : "Suse Linux"
         },
         "SERVER2" : {
            "ip" : "10.1.2.4",
            "os" : "Windows 10"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

(This is different than zdim's first solution.)

Note that I got rid of the nested loops because they are nasty. For a few items, it's not a problem. But performance would suffer is `@servers` or `@details` would become large. So it's a bad idea, and a bad habit to get into.

---

Having an array which only even has a single element is weird. Did you perhaps want

```json
{
   "instance" : {
      "SERVER1" : {
         "ip" : "10.1.2.3",
         "os" : "Suse Linux"
      },
      "SERVER2" : {
         "ip" : "10.1.2.4",
         "os" : "Windows 10"
      }
   }
}
```

This would be achieved by replacing

```perl
my $data = { instance => \@instances };
```

with

```perl
my $data = { instance => \%instance };
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Let me test this vs the original code and get back to you.